# How to ensure that the index also gets deleted post a deletion query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database which has 1 billion records, and every day new 12 million records are inserted into the table.

I have a simple delete query, which deletes the rows which are old.

Sample delete query:

```
where last_updated >= '2022-10-20 00:00:00' 
  and last_updated < '2022-10-21 00:00:00';
```

This query deletes the data for 1 day, and table has an index on `last_updated`.

How do i make sure that the index is also deleted after the execution of above query?

I tried looking for answers but could not find a relevant answer.

Comment: Did you create separate indexes for each day? If so, you have to drop them as well: drop index ….;

Comment: Why would want to drop the index? If you are worried about non-relevant index entries those will be cleaned up by the next `autovacuum`. Or if you want you can do a manual [VACUUM](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-vacuum.html)

Comment: Since even a partial index is tied to the table and not the records in it, you need to drop it manually in a separate query. If your aim is to save space, I think that the nearest `reindex` or `vacuum` will update and empty the indexes covering the deleted range, so they will no longer really consume space, although it's still good practice to drop them. To find the specific index corresponding to the rows you're deleting you could compare your where clause to `indexdef` column of `pg_catalog.pg_indexes`. You could use dynamic sql in a function or even a trigger to emulate a cascade behaviour.

Comment: Please show the DDL for that table. The good news is that in most circumstances, the database engine takes care of removing pointers from the index when  you delete rows. If you show DDL, we can verify that this is working in your case too.

Comment: @NevilleKuyt DDL has `with (autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor = 0.010);` in place.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver if it's about good practices, indices for no more required data need to be dropped. Yes but, if this is a scheduled delete which happens daily. Manual Vaccum will be an overhead, right?

Comment: You have not shown what the indexes are so it is hard to come up with a specific answer. The `autovacuum/vacuum`  is going to run automatically or need to be run manually to deal with the deleted rows anyway, so the overhead is already there.

Comment: Please show the full DDL - table and indices.

Comment: There is no such thing as deleting an index.  You DROP an index, or clean it up with VACUUM or autovacuum, or REINDEX it.  It isn't clear which of those things you are aiming for.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting data is a two-step process in PostgreSQL: first, the rows are marked as deleted and become invisible. Later, autovacuum runs `VACUUM` on the table, which actually deletes the data and the index entries that point to it. `VACUUM` will free space inside the table and the index, but the files typically won't become smaller (only emptier). The free space can be reused for new data.

The king's way to a requirement like yours is partitioning. Use range partitioning so that you can drop a partition rather than running `DELETE`. That will be fast as lightning, and the space is reclaimed immediately.